# How to perform a simple t-test in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, t-test

My goal is to perform a t-test in Spark Scala with the method documented on https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/test/StudentTTest.html. Let's assume my data is given in a data frame:

```
val df = Seq((1, 3), (-2, 5), (0, 4), (3, -1), (2, -1)).toDF("group1", "group2")
```

Now, I tried

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test
val ttestResult = test.StudentTTest(df)
```

but this got me an error: `<console>:29: error: object StudentTTest in package test cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are probably using Spark 2.2 or Spark 2.3 which have deprecated the method. See org.apache.spark.ml.stat and org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package